# MySQL Wrong Restore Data Recovery

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, recovery

I'm almost certain about the answer, but the situation is so critical that I have to ask this question even though I'm %99 sure about the answer.

Someone in our office made a backup of a **MySQL** database and he restored it on a wrong destination database overwriting everything on that destination (The schema of both databases were the same). According to the structure of the MySQL backup files I know that the restore operation drops all the tables first and then creates them and fills them up with the backed up data. **The question is does the restore module keeps the old data anywhere? Is there anyway of retrieving any of the old data? (logs?.. etc.)**

Comment: I'm referring to the restore tool in the Administrative Tools of MySQL GUI Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you have replicated slaves, or you used to, and have [binary logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html). Even then you'd need an old copy of the database you can restore, and to configure replication again.

Comment: I would think that they would not have old enough logs unless they just added the old data say within the last 7 days.

Comment: Surprisingly there are no backups on that server. I also found some articles talking about restoring the data files in case the tables were MyISAM. But I think none of them really work in such a severe situation